# What is the purpose of players attempting to change a faction's influence?

Tags: elite-dangerous

There are many guides that show how you can get factions to grow and take over stations and systems.  The various things you do for them will increase their influence, and can result in a civil war and a change of controlling faction.

My question is - what is the benefit to the player for doing this?  There is the immediate rep benefit of becoming Allied opening up new missions and possibly new equipment, but beyond that, is there some other driver?

It isn't as if you can *join* a faction, and so get rewarded for your faction growing (other than through a conflict zone).

So what is it for?  Roleplaying?

Answer (score 6):

There is a large element of roleplaying and fun to the reasoning behind players supporting certain minor factions, but there is also a gameplay element that has to do with PowerPlay.

When dealing with a system that you power wants to expand into, control, fortify, etc. It's much better if it has a government that matches the power's ideal, as in it cuts the requirement needed.

The same tactic can be used to undermine powers, by changing the government to the one a power does not get along with, the cost of upkeep is increased.

Comment: So no benefit outside of Powerplay? I haven't pledged.

Comment: not really, I guess knocking a piracy government out of power will reduce that sort of activity in the system, though.